# Tap gesture works very well in simulator but not working on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Here's my code:

```
// in viewdidload

UITapGestureRecognizer* gestureRecognizer_businessType = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pickerViewTapGestureRecognized:)];
gestureRecognizer_businessType.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

[busType_pickerView  addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer_businessType];


// in pickerViewTapGestureRecognized method

CGPoint point_businessType = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:busType_pickerView];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(locationRect, point_businessType))
{
    //code execution

}
else
{

}


///pickerview code


busType_pickerViewContainer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216);
busType_pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216);
busType_pickerView.hidden = NO;
busType_pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

[busType_pickerViewContainer addSubview:busType_pickerView];
[busType_viewController.view addSubview:busType_pickerViewContainer];

busType_popOverForPicker = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:busType_viewController];
busType_popOverForPicker.delegate = self;
busType_pickerView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[busType_popOverForPicker setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 216) animated:NO];
[busType_popOverForPicker presentPopoverFromRect:businessTypeBtn.frame inView:self.businessDetailsView  permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown| UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft|UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight) animated:YES];
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're attaching a tap gesture recognizer to a UIPickerView the picker view and the gesture recognizer are probably fighting over the taps. The simulator is only a simulation of iOS, and runs against different frameworks than iOS. Just because it works on the simulator does not mean it will work on an actual device. I've run into this quite a few times.